# Console logging data gives me an empty array(line 12), I noticed that the value is logged in the console even before the filter function is finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React console logs the data variable before the filter function is finished. I want to load the data into the data variable if the blog id matched the params id. But data variable is console logged before the function is finished.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BlogDataContext } from "../contexts/BlogDataContext";

export default function BlogPage({ match }) {
  var Id = match.params.id;
  const context = useContext(BlogDataContext);
  const [Blog, setBlog] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    var data = context.filter((b) => {
      return b._id === Id;
    });
    console.log(data);
    setBlog(data);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div style={{ color: "red" }} className="BlogPage">
      hello
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what is output of `console.log(data, context);` ?

Comment: context also turned out to be empty. Thats strange, because when i console log context out of the useEffect, first it prints an empty array and then it prints the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put context in useEffect dependency array:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BlogDataContext } from "../contexts/BlogDataContext";

export default function BlogPage({ match }) {
  var Id = match.params.id;
  const context = useContext(BlogDataContext);
  const [Blog, setBlog] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    var data = context.filter((b) => {
      return b._id === Id;
    });
    console.log(data);
    setBlog(data);
  }, [context]);
  return (
    <div style={{ color: "red" }} className="BlogPage">
      hello
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It does work, but can you explain why context was empty at first?

Comment: Because useEffect dependency array follow after changes for certain variables. If your dependecy array is empty it just does that first time when component mount (if component mount before context data gets filled you will get an empty array). So you need to make sure to fill dependency array always with variables that you need to follow and get their last values.